# What is the best way to search for a key in multiple dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I know we can search for a key in Python like this:

```
if key in myDict:
    #Do something here
```

I know we can extend this and search for the key in multiple dictionaries using elif statement

```
if key in myDict_1:
    #Do something here
elif key in myDict_2:
    #Do something here
```

or by doing

```
if key in (myDict_1.keys() + myDict_2.keys()):
    #Do something here
```

But is there a more succinct way to search for key in Python in two different dicts without using if-else or adding the list of keys explicitly ?

Comment: `if any(key in d for d in dicts): # do something`

Comment: or for just two dicts you can keep it simple and do `if key in dict1 or key in dict2`

Comment: I guess not. You have to use `if, elif` also this will not help `if key in (myDict_1.keys() + myDict_2.keys())` because you don't know later from which dict keys the condition satisfied.

Comment: You could also write your own helper method: `def in_any(x, *iterables): return any(x in i for i in iterables)`, then call it like `if in_any(key, dic1, dict2)`

Comment: @AamirAdnan in this particular case I don't need to know which dict() it is in. Zero's answer takes care of that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question as written is:

```
if any(key in d for d in dicts):
    # do something
```

If you need to know which dictionary or dictionaries contain the key, you can use [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> d1 = dict(zip("kapow", "squee"))
>>> d2 = dict(zip("bar", "foo"))
>>> d3 = dict(zip("xyz", "abc"))
>>> dicts = d1, d2, d3

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dicts)
({'a': 'q', 'k': 's', 'o': 'e', 'p': 'u', 'w': 'e'},
{'a': 'o', 'b': 'f', 'r': 'o'},
{'x': 'a', 'y': 'b', 'z': 'c'})

>>> from itertools import compress
>>> for d_with_key in compress(dicts, ("a" in d for d in dicts)):
...     print(d_with_key)
... 
{'a': 'q', 'p': 'u', 'k': 's', 'w': 'e', 'o': 'e'}
{'a': 'o', 'r': 'o', 'b': 'f'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be as Zero wrote:

```
if any(key in d for d in dicts): # do something
```

**Fixing after reading comments below, thanks to @jwodder:**

But you can also create a tuple of the keys of both (or more) dictionaries using the `itertools.chain` function.

```
>>> a = {1:2}
>>> b = {3:4}
>>> c = {5:6, 7:8}
>>> print(tuple(itertools.chain(a, b, c)))
(1, 3, 5, 7)
```

so you also can :

```
if x in tuple(itertools.chain(a, b, c)):
    # Do something
```

Comment: ```print(list(zip(a,b,c))[0])``` should produce a list, no?

Comment: nop, look at the `[0]` at the end, just before the closing `)`

Comment: Ooh, sneaky.  Is this 3.x only?  When I run ```list(zip({5:'a'},{6,'b'}))[0]``` on 2.7 I get ```(5, 'b')```

Comment: @wnnmaw: I believe that's because your second argument to `zip` is actually a `set`, not `dict`, since you used `,` instead of `:`.

Answer (score 1):

A little list comprehension is also possible here; if you're simply trying to ascertain if a key is in a container of dicts, `any()` does exactly that; if you want to get the dict (or dicts) back and work with them, perhaps something like this would suffice:

```
>>> def get_dicts_with_key(some_key, *dicts):
...     return [d for d in dicts if some_key in d]

>>> dict1 = {"hey":123}
>>> dict2 = {"wait":456}
>>> get_dicts_with_key('hey', dict1, dict2)
[{'hey': 123}]
>>> get_dicts_with_key('wait', dict1, dict2)
[{'wait': 456}]
>>> get_dicts_with_key('complaint', dict1, dict2)
[]
```

If the keys were present in either dict, both would be returned, as such:

```
>>> dict1['complaint'] = 777
>>> dict2['complaint'] = 888
>>> get_dicts_with_key('complaint', dict1, dict2)
[{'complaint': 777, 'hey': 123}, {'complaint': 888, 'wait': 456}]
>>>
```

Comment: Consider changing `dict` to `d` in your list comprehension to avoid shadowing the `dict` type.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your dicts in an iterable like a list and simple loop over then? You can express it as a function like so.

```
def has_key(key, my_dicts):
    for my_dict in my_dicts:
        if key in my_dict:
            return True
    return False
```

It would be used like so.

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
>>> dict2 = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
>>> has_key('b', [dict1, dict2])
True
```